# View data doesn't update although new data is coming from websockets

Tags: angular, signalr

I have a controller that maintains displaying logs to my web app. Logs are sent via SignalR from an ASP.NET Core API.

The case is when I first enter the site, new incoming logs are displayed correctly. But when I switch to another page of my web app and come back to logs, although I can see new logs are incoming in the console, the view of Logs controller doesn't update.

My logs controller looks like this:

```
export class LoggerComponent implements OnInit {
    hubConnection: HubConnection;
    public logs: Array<LogMessage> = new Array<LogMessage>();

    constructor(private alertService: AlertService,
                private loaderService: LoaderService,
                private signalRHandler: SignalRHandler,
                ) {
      // Here I subscribe to event that is called if WebSocket connection was 
      // lost and renewed so I can acquire new instance of HubCOnnection
      // and subscribe to Hub events
      this.signalRHandler.onAcquireNewHubInstance.subscribe((acquire) => {
          if (acquire) {
           this.acquireHubInstance();
          }
      });
    }

    ngOnInit() { 
     // As you can see I tried to re-subscribe to HubEvents and this works 
     // but when I refresh the app the log messages are duplicated.
     //this.acquireHubInstance();
    }

    acquireHubInstance() {
      this.hubConnection = this.signalRHandler.hubConnection;
      this.hubConnection.on('BroadcastLogMessage', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        if (this.logs.length < 2000) {
            this.logs.push(data);
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest instead of using `new Array()` instead use `rxjs BehaviorSubject` and subscribe to the observable in `ngOnInit` instead calling the method again

Comment: I did as you said but the result is: on page load everything is fine, but when I switch to other view and come back to Logs, although new logs are incoming in the console the view becomes blank and is not appending with new messages.

Comment: You need to add the data to the list of behavior subject. Here is the sample code for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4wjed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared.service.ts Hope this might help you